# When selection upon a select box changes, change the value for all form fields with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery

When the user makes a selection on a select box with id `some_select_box`:

- I want to grab the value that was selected
- I want to grab all form fields on the page that have the class `hidden_search_box` and change all their values to match the selected value.

I am missing something obvious here in my code:

```
$(document).on('change', '#some_select_box', function () {
  var selected_value = this.value;
  $(".hidden_search_box").each(function () {
    this.value = selected_value;
  });
});
```

**Answer**: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smn0axbf/3/)

Comment: Could you set up a JSFiddle?

Comment: Also, just noticed you don't close the  quotes here -> $(".hidden_search_box)

Comment: working on a jsfiddle now

Comment: Check the first answer, I believe that's what you want

Comment: @SatejS made js fiddle to recreate situation.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/k4p49o3h/ - you need to add jQuery to the fiddle - click the icon next to `javascript` in the top right side of `js` panel then select jQuery under libraries

Comment: @ArunPJohny would you mind posting an answer so that I can give you credit? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in your code, in `$(".hidden_search_box")`, there's a double-quote missing.

```
$(function() {
  $(document).on('change', '#some_select_box', function() {
    var selected_value = this.value;
    $(".hidden_search_box").each(function() {
      debugger;
      this.value = selected_value;
    });
  });
})
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ArcaneCraeda/2pf8v0nc/5/)

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your js fiddle is, you haven't added jQuery library to it, so you should be having an error like `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` in your console.

To add jQuery to the fiddle, in the javascript panel, click on the icon on the top right and select jQuery under library dropdown.

Comment: Thanks!  I went ahead and marked the above one as the answer.  If you want: I can change it to your answer if you provide your js fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).on('change', '#some_select_box', function () {
    $(".hidden_search_box").val(this.val());
    $(".hidden_search_box option[value='"+this.val()+"']").attr('selected','selected');

});
```